# Representation/Encoding error after converting project from VS2008 to Vs2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Today I switched from VS2008 to VS2010. Due to this I converted one of my projects to use it in VS2010. In this project I use korean characters.

In VS2008 the characters were shown correctly on labels. In VS2010 the characters aren't displayed. Only some squaresymbols as replacement.

In the sourcecode in both projects the korean characters are shown correct. Also I've nothing changed. Not even the font or something else. So the "error" must happen during the conversion.

How can i fix this? I hope you understand my crappy english and can help me.

Comment: This sounds like a serious bug with the converter software. Can you test whether this also happens with the smallest project containing Korean characters? If so, could you upload the converted testproject (not your original!) somewhere?

Comment: Another thought: try [this free tool](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm) to convert back to 2008. It won't change the source files, nor the encoding. Try to open the back-converted project in VS2008. If this runs correctly, the problem is with incompatible encoding of your source files. If you still see blocks, the problem is caused by the converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the SP1 for VS2010. After that all characters were shown correctly, without converting the project another time.

So it seems that there's no problem with the converter tool at all, but a general bug in VS2010.

In short: Install VS2010 SP1 to fix incorrect presentation of korean characters.

Comment: Good to hear that it's solved. If you want, you can mark your own answer after two days as an accepted answer.